# Is it bad to have file name as post variable?

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I don't know if there is a way for someone to potentially abuse this. What is a workaround? I do not want someone to be able to abuse my server by downloading content this way.

There is an option to re-email a shipping label. I basically have it setup so there is no database work besides the preparation of the page. The only other method I can think of is to have the post variable the ID of the row and then pull the file name from there.

So, is it unsafe to have a filename as a post variable (that could potentially be tampered with)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only unsafe if you're going to do something like `readfile()` or `include()` on it.

Using the row ID would be better, but even with this you still need to consider if the user should be allowed to access the file (to avoid random id=1 id=2 id=3 testing).

Comment: I would be attaching it to an email that is sent to a user. So, `fopen()` and `fread()`

Comment: Use the row ID. If attaching to an email, you still need a check to ensure the user is allowed access - unless of course all users have access to all files.

Comment: @NickMcCally no problem. If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted (click the tick) so that others can see which questions need answers and which don't.

Answer (score 2):

You should never trust incoming data. POST requests can be abused as well as GET requests, so in the worst case your website could be a mean of XSS attacks, or could be used as a spamming node.

The thing to do is sending, apart from filename or entry ID, some hash, and then checking whether these two match, i.e. is the entry associated with this hash. Therefore simply trying different IDs will not work, since abuser would have to guess proper hash as well. A word of advice: hash not only id, or filename, but time of sending e-mail and some salt as well.

Comment: A hash wouldn't secure it if certain files were only accessible to selected users because the wrong user with the correct hash and ID can still access the file. In that case it should be verified if the user has permission to access the file, rather than 'security through obscurity'.

Comment: With this method, I wouldn't be doing the database pull from above? Or are you suggesting that method as well as hashing the data?

Comment: @MrCode: of course, when you have an option to use traditional authorization, you should check for permissions. But sometimes it is not possible, i.e. sending an e-mail to reset password or sending a file to a non-user. But then again, why not use attachment? It would be better.

Comment: @NickMcCally - you always do the database check. Using raw input data is a bad idea. If you can authorize user, then do it and don't use hash, in the other case - use hash and check if it is proper for requested file.